# PDO Exception - could not find driver (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I`m developing application with Laravel 4. When I try to login in my application I recieve:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\project\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:47
```

I am using WAMP as a server management tool and MySQL as database. In my php.ini I`ve enabled those extensions:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_shmop.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_dblib.dll
```

In my database.php the default db is mysql.

In the phpinfo() i can see PDO and PDO_MYSQL are enabled. After changes I`ve restarted the server.

Still getting the error. What am I missing ?

Comment: Is your `php_mysql` extension enabled?

Comment: yes  `extension=php_mysql.dll 
          extension=php_mysqli.dll`

Comment: Line 47 should be `return new PDO($dsn, ...`. When you replace that line with `die('dsn is '.$dsn);` (having a backup of the original of course) does it really show a PDO_MYSQL dsn afterwards (i.e. one that starts with `mysql:host=...`)?

Comment: neither `php_mysql.dll` nor `php_mysqli.dll` is needed for PDO/Mysql, only `php_pdo_mysql.dll` - which you have in your php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need help. After enabled extension I just restarted apache and works.